# How to get Spring Webflow started with link

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-webflow

I want to use Spring Webflow to do a checkout for an online store. I have looked at a couple of tutorials to figure out how to configure everything, but I can't get it to work. I think the problem may be with the url for the checkout, but I can't find any sources explaining how to fire off the first action-state.

My current code:

```
<strong>checkout-flow.xml</strong>
    <var name="order" class="com.webstore.domain.Order"/>

    <action-state id="addCartToOrder">
        <evaluate expression="cartService.validate(requestParameters.cartId)" result="order.cart" />
        <transition to="invalidCartWarning" on-exception="com.webstore.exception.InvalidCartException" />
        <transition to="collectCustomerInfo" />
    </action-state>
```

**WebFlowConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder()
                .addFlowLocation("/templates/flows/checkout/checkout-flow.xml", "checkout")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
        FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
        handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());

        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
        FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
        handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);

        return handlerAdapter;
    }
}
```

[Current Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrKZH.jpg)

I think the problem is how the URL is configured... I have tried several combinations, so I am not sure how to put this together... currently it is:

```
<a th:href="@{/flows/checkout}"> Check out  </a>
```

But this does not work. Any advice on where I am going wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the issue just that your flow is in `templates/flows.checkout`, but you're referencing it in `templates/flows/checkout`?

Comment: @dbreaux Using intellij, and it just displays empty folders like that in a similiar way to packages... actual directory is `templates/flow/checkout`... however, I have managed to find a solution to the problem...
As it turns out I needed to prefix `classpath:` in the webflowconfig file... from other sources I've consulted, it seems to be the way to do it with Spring Boot...

Comment: Glad to hear you found solution. Suggest you add that as an answer and accept it. For future searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I needed to prefix `classpath:` in the webflowconfig file... from other sources I've consulted, it seems to be the way to do it with Spring Boot, as the file structure is different when packaged as a jar.